# django heroku manage.py Import Error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am doing the djangogirls tutorial and very new to programming, if this helps anyone else that's searching for a solution.

I am getting the following `Import Error` after trying to do `heroku run python manage.py migrate`:

```
Running `python manage.py migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8303
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_c
ommand_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named blog
```

My settings.py file is as follows:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '1l8)#&q8r_wwev1r9mm8q5ezz8p#)rvg(l4%(t^-t8s4bva2+r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Directory:
    -blog
        - migrations
        - **init**.py
        - admin.py
        - models.py
        - (a few more)
    - mysite
    - myvenv
    - manage.py
    - (a few more)

Comment: Have you created blog app? Does it run on local environment?

Comment: Yes, I ran "python manage.py startapp blog"  to create it. I was committing all folders to heroku and it failed.  Initially this had work on local environtment, and now I tried to do it w/o creating from scratch and cannot manage how to start the app. (i.e. if i just  start my local env, and then "python manage.py runserver" it does not work.  Again i'm a very big newbie, so please forgive "easy" mistakes.

Comment: What error you get when you run `python manage.py runserver` on local environment?

Comment: my mistake, I only went to the (port?) address which said "it worked!" but did not show my blog.  Then i went to the admin page and I see the blog is up and running without any loss of data. So yes, it works on the local environment.

Comment: I had an issue where my .gitignore was ignoring blog as opposed to the name of my virtual environment (which I formally named blog).

Comment: After modifying .gitignore `git add . `     
 `git commit -m "your message"`     `git push heroku master`